# Bash complaining "no such file or directory" in for loop

Tags: bash

I have a list of file in variable `list_of_files`. So if I run the following commands

```
for file_path in $list_of_files; do
  echo "=${file_path}="
done
```

It gives me this

```
=./a.py=
=./b.py=
=./c.py=
```

which means `file_path` contains a relative path to file, without any redundant spaces before or after.

But if I use `cat` instead of `echo`, it complains "No such file or directory"

```
for file_path in $list_of_files; do
  cat ${file_path}
done
```

But what's interesting is, if I call `cat` directly `cat ./a.py`, it works.

It is not a cat-specific problem. It turns out if I check the file existence using `if` statement, it tells me those files do not exist.

```
for file_path in $list_of_files; do
  if [ -f "$file_path" ]
  then
    echo 'OK'
  else
    echo 'NO'
  fi
done
```

Result:

```
NO
NO
NO
```

Tried following approaches, but also failed.

- Use full absolute path
- Remove `./` from all file paths

Comment: Wild hunch -- ensure `$list_of_files` doesn't have any extraneous/improper line terminators (`\r\n` vs `\n`).

Comment: 1: add a `pwd` to your script, to verify that you're in the directory you think you are. 2: add a `set -x` to your script, to print each command being executed -- does it look reasonable?

Comment: does `cat ./a.py` work inside the script?

Comment: @SnildDolkow (1) verified that `pwd` shows the correct path (2) used `set -x`, copied the command and manully run them successfully

Comment: @keithmo No, they don't. That is why I `echo "=${file_path}="`.

Comment: You should have the command `od` available (it is in most Linux installs). Test if you have it with `man od`. If the manual is installed, the command should be also. If so, then execute this command: `echo "$list_of_files" | od -An -tcx1` and post the result here. That will show any odd character that the variable might contain.

Comment: @BinaryZebra oh that's so interesting! So $list_of_files is actually colored. So it contains some special characters for coloring purpose but hidden!

Comment: Where did `$list_of_files` come from? The output from `ls`?

Comment: @EtanReisner no, it comes from our internal tool. but I believe it is just a wrap of `grep`.

Comment: Whatever the source it is is broken and needs to be fixed. It should not be spitting out terminal color codes when its output is not a terminal.

Answer (score 3):

The reason turns out to be that `$list_of_files` is colored. So it contains some special characters for coloring purpose but hidden!

I found that using `echo "$list_of_files" | od -An -tcx1` (thanks to @BinaryZebra), which displays all the junks coloring the file names.

By using `sed -r "s:\x1B\[[0-9;]*[mK]::g"`, I ruled out those magic bits!